# Swift: MongoDB Realm is not syncing when queried

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I'm not getting the latest data in my MongoDB cluster when I query the realm in swift. I initially had about 4000 data in the realm and that synced to mobile but when I increased the data to about 10,000 it does not sync the latest just what was there before. I noticed this print out when the app starts up.

> Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = true, async open = false, client reset = false.

this is how I try to sync when the starts up

```
struct AppRootView: View {
@State var homeLink = false // <- add here
@State var loginLink = false
@State private var selection: String? = nil


var body: some View {
  NavigationView { // <- wrap in the `NavigationView`
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("App")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
        
        NavigationLink(destination: homeMainView(), tag: "home", selection: $selection) {EmptyView()}
        NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), tag: "login", selection: $selection) {EmptyView()}
    }

 }
.onAppear(perform: handleSignIn)
.frame(minWidth: 0,
       maxWidth: .infinity,
       minHeight: 0,
       maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.yellow)
}

func handleSignIn() {
  print("HANDLING SIGNING IN")
  if let _ = app.currentUser() {
    print("USER IS LOGGED IN ALREADY")
    self.handleRealmSync()

    self.selection = "home" // <- activate the `NavigationLink`
} else {
    print("USER NEEDS TO LOGIN")
    self.selection = "login"
    print("not logged in; present sign in/signup view")
 }
 }

 func handleRealmSync(){
 let user = app.currentUser()
 let partitionValue = "store=walmart"

 Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user!.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue),

    callback: { (maybeRealm, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
        }
        guard let realm = maybeRealm else {
            fatalError("realm is nil!")
        }
        // realm opened
        print("Realm SYNC IS OPENED")
     })
  }
 }
```

I get a print out "Realm SYNC IS OPENED" which makes me think it should be but this

> Realm exists = true, async open = false

appears to be in conflict. Then I checked MongoDB Realm Log on Sync Session. This is the message

> ["Session closed after receiving UNBIND event"]

it shows that the sync is not happening. What could be preventing the syncing ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code is a bit vague; you've included the initial async connection with Realm but then do nothing with Realm thereafter. Can you clarify and update the question with reduced code (eliminate the UI stuff) that demonstrates the issue? e.g. the `handleRealmSync` function is important and then whatever code you're using to access realm after that. Please take a moment and review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need to make sure the `Realm` isn't deinitialized.

You could create a `@State` property to store the `Realm` instance received in the callback:

```
@State var realm:Realm?
```

and

```
 Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: user!.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue)) { (maybeRealm, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
        }
        guard let realm = maybeRealm else {
            fatalError("realm is nil!")
        }
        // realm opened
        print("Realm SYNC IS OPENED")
        self.realm = maybeRealm
     }
  }
```